# Grails cascade delete on parent is deleting child records one by one

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Using Grails 2.4.4, Hibernate 4.3.6.1 plugin...

We have a domain object with a parent/child one-to-many relationship using a hasMany/belongsTo. When deleting the parent record, Grails cascades the deletes to the child records. However, when looking at the SQL, I see that Grails is fetching the child records and deleting them one-by-one using `delete ... where id = ? and version = ?`

This is a horribly inefficient way to delete the child records and I'm fairly sure Grails didn't do this when I initially wrote this code (I can't find anything that specifically causes this behavior).

I would expect Grails/Hibernate to run a query more like:

`delete from Child where parent_id = ?`

So that all child records are deleting in one query, instead of thousands of queries.

Is there something in the mappings/config that would cause Grails to behave in this manner?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that since you are using optimistic locking (e.g. you haven't disabled version) on your child instances it must check each instance by version, and thus delete them one at a time. This is one of the many gotchas when using GORM.

Comment: Interesting, I can certainly disable optimistic locking and see if it changes the behavior. Generally speaking, I think optimistic locking is a false sense of security anyway.

Comment: So removing the optimistic locking has no affect other than to remove the `version = ?` part from the delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to explicitly delete the child objects and the parent object in a transactional service method. Remove the `hasMany` collection, and convert the `belongsTo` to a regular property, e.g.

```
class Author {
   String name
}
```

and

```
class Book {
   String title
   Author author
}
```

and then you can efficiently delete the books and the author in two queries:

```
void deleteAuthor(Author a) {
   Book.where { author == a }.deleteAll()
   a.delete()
}
```

Watch [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) which shows additional reasons why you should avoid using collections.

Comment: This may be true, however, I still think something has changed in GORM to cause this. I'm almost positive that I profiled this before and GORM generated SQL which deleted the child via the `parent_id`.

Comment: I tried it in a 2.0.4 app and it uses the same N+1 approach

Comment: Thanks for checking. I also did some tests and came to the same conclusion. I think I'm in a state of denial that the cascade algorithm could possibly be that bad by default.

Comment: Watch the presentation - it's worse than you think :)